# circuit datasheet Analysis Request

Tags: circuit-analysis, datasheet

title : LB1630 datasheet

Electrical Characteristics at Ta = 25

1. Output Saturation Voltage ( upper side + lower side )
2. Output Sustain Voltage
3. Input Current
4. Reverse Current
5. Forward Voltage
6. Current Dissipation

I don't know about six things.
I'd appreciate it if you could tell me in detail.

[image]

Also, is the 10uF capacitor used for power stabilization?

Comment: *I don't know about five things* Oh, there are **millions** of things I do not know about ;-)  You will need to be more specific than "5 things". *Also, is the 10uF capacitor used for power stabilization?* It is for **supply decoupling** which is similar to "stabilizing the supply voltage".

Comment: Looks like homework, have you taken a course on reading data sheets. I can repeat everything you show in the chart but to answer your question I need to know what the 5 things you need to know. If you have done some research on this let us know what you found.

Comment: It's not homework.
I think it would be good to think of it as a hobby.
Are there any datasheet reading courses?
please tell me where it is
I know the name of the function, but I have no idea what it does.
If you can't solve it here, you'll have to do it another way.

Answer (score 1):

Many of those terms are explaned in a number of places and can be found by web searching. One is much less commonly defined and ine is unusual in its usage.

> Output Saturation Voltage ( upper side + lower side )

The voltage drop across input and output stages when fully on under specified conditions.

> Output Sustain Voltage

Maximum continuous voltage that can be applied to the output.
Better shown as Voutmax. This may be higher than the supply voltage in the case of an IC.
This is the uncommonly defined one.

> Input Current

Maximum current allowed to be drawn by the device.

> Reverse Current

Maximum current flow whan reverse to on voltage is applied (usually relates to a diode or device in off condition with reverse polarity applied)

> Forward Voltage

Voltage drop when on or forward viased (usually diodes or similar)

> Current Dissipation

This is a somewhat unusual term.
They mean maximum current under specified conditions.
"Dissipation" is usually used for power.

---

Including a link to a datasheet is useful if one is available.

Comment: Thank you very much